# The final contents of the array from algorithm

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Im student from Poland and I have little knowledge about the operation of this algorithm.

Here is the algorithm:

```
n <- 1
for i = 1,2, ..., k do
    n <- 2 * n
s <- 1
while s < n do
    j <- 1
    while j < n do
        if A[j] > A[j+s]
            switch places of( A[j], A[j+s] )
        j <- j+2s
    s <- 2s
return A[1], A[2], ... , A[n]
```

And here is link to table in polish language but I will try my best to translate it (6.1 table).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/At6Vz.jpg

- First column is the value of k
- Second column means "The initial value of the array"
- Third column means "The final value of the array"

And I want to know how for array [4,3,1,2] it completed with [1,4,3,2]. Can somebody explain how this algorithm works for this example?

Comment: You can also explain me it for the [2,3,4,1] array instead.

Comment: Is the algorithm at the top of the imgur picture supposed to match the algorithm typed in this question?

Comment: @FriedSaucePots exactly, I tried my best to translate these commands to english.

Comment: @FriedSaucePots sorry for errors in algorithm, and thanks for edit :D Anyway, you know how to explain it for me? I will be very glad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you'll want to do is hand trace your code. Here's a [small video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TZss5ukwN8s) on how to hand trace code. You can also search google for "hand trace code".

It's a tedious process but it will be what you want to do when you need to understand how an algorithm executes.

---

One little side hint, the first bit of code . . .

```
n <- 1
for i = 1,2, ..., k do
    n <- 2 * n
```

This is just calculating `n = 2^k`. Possibly try hand tracing the first three lines of code for practice then try hand tracing the rest.